# psycopg2: Error inserting with foreign keys

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psycopg2

I am trying to first insert a line on a table "lf_calculator_user" then get the id of the line I just inserted and use that id to insert it as a foreign key into another record on a the table "lf_calculator_request".
Here is my code:

```
 if event["email"] is not None:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO lf_calculator_user (email) VALUES (%(email)s) ON CONFLICT (email) DO UPDATE SET email = EXCLUDED.email;", event)
        cursor.execute('SELECT LASTVAL()')
        lastid = cursor.fetchone()[0]
        if lastid is not None: 
            if event["amount"] is not None: 
                if event["date"] is not None:
                    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO lf_calculator_request (email_id, amount, invoice_due_date) VALUES ('+ str(lastid) +', %(amount)s, %(date)s);', event)
```

I get a strange error saying that email_id is not a column on the table "lf_calculator_user" which obviously isn't it is a column on "lf_calculator_request" as a foreign key. What am I missing ?

Here is the error:

```
psycopg2.IntegrityError: insert or update on table "lf_calculator_request" violates foreign key constraint "lf_calculatorrequest_email_id_fkey"DETAIL:  Key (email_id)=(21) is not present in table "lf_calculator_user".
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try more detailed logging in Postgresql and the issue may become more obvious.
Update the postgresql.conf (and restart)

## log_min_duration_statement = -1    # -1 is disabled, 0 logs all statements

log_min_duration_statement = 0